# When I back to previous page in react native webview app, it's reloading page again

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a dynamic website https://pharmogram.in. I converted into react native webview app.but problem is when I click a link on home page to go to another page and back to previous page ..... Previous page reloads again fully data.

Pls suggest me what I do

here is code...

```js
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import {StatusBar,Text,View,} from 'react-native';
import React, { useRef, useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import { BackHandler,ActivityIndicator,StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    activityIndicatorStyle: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });
  const ActivityIndicatorElement = () => {
    return (
      <ActivityIndicator
        color="#009688"
        size="large"
        style={styles.activityIndicatorStyle}
      />
    );
  };
  const webView = useRef<WebView>(null);

  const [canGoBack, setCanGoBack] = useState(false);

  const handleBack = useCallback(() => {
    if (canGoBack && webView.current) {
      webView.current.goBack();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }, [canGoBack]);

  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handleBack);
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handleBack);
    };
  }, [handleBack]);

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" backgroundColor="#ffffff"/>
      <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']} 
        javaScriptEnabled={true} 
        geolocationEnabled={ true }
        ref={webView}
        source={{ uri: "https://pharmogram.in/" }}
        onLoadProgress={(event) => setCanGoBack(event.nativeEvent.canGoBack)}
      />
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: can you upload here screen shot so it can be help us

Comment: Have you tried  using  injectedJavaScript? this will prevent reloading and maintain the state of  the web

Comment: Yes I did..But problem is same .